# Javascript anonymous function argument passing (wrox professionnal javascript p188)

Tags: javascript

Wrox Profesionnal Javascript p188
I don't understand this part at line 8 where the anonymous function already have an argument of num, but how can (i) is copied into the argument num. Normally a function would stop at the closing bracket }, adding (i) doesn't make sense for me.

```
function createFunctions(){
    var result = new Array();
    for (var i=0; i < 10; i++){
       result[i] = function(num){
         return function(){
           return num;
         };
       }(i);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is short hand for calling the function and passing it the parameter i.  It's like doing this:

```
function createFunctions(){
    var result = new Array();
    for (var i=0; i < 10; i++){
        result[i] = myFunction(i);
    }
    return result;
}

function myFunction(num){
    return function(){
        return num;
    }
}
```

Thinking of myFunction as the anonymous function my help you understand what's going on, so instead of myFunction(i) you have function(num){...}(i);

Comment: I like to know is (i) a function expression? if not is there a name for this type of typing?

Answer (score 1):

It's a closure and a self executing function. `i` is being "saved" in the scope of the returned function.

```
var test = "ONE";
var scoped = function () {
    alert(test);
}
var saved_scoped = (function (value) {
    return function () {
        alert(value);
    }
})(test);

test = "NOT ONE!";
scoped(); // alerts NOT ONE!
saved_scoped(); // alerts ONE
```

So you execute the function with the `(i)` immediately. Then return a function with the `i` value saved.